# how to itrate throw an array after a map and retrun new array after if else conditaion

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object

`data.risk.scatterIndices.investments.map((el: any) => el.name) || []`

I have this map function that return an array like that:

`["pension","realestate","balance","kupot"]`

this is the conditaion i want to use to translate this array to a new array

```
`
if(key === balance){
key = 'עוש ומזומן'
}else if(key ===  realestate){
key = 'נדלן'
}else if(key === pension){
 key = 'פנסיה'
}else if(key ===  kupot){
 key = 'קופות'
}
`
```

expected output is `["קופות","עוש ומזומן","נדלן","פנסיה"]`

how i could done it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `map`

```js
const arr = ['pension', 'realestate', 'balance', 'kupot']

const res = arr.map(key => {
  if (key === 'balance') {
    return 'עוש ומזומן'
  } else if (key === 'realestate') {
    return 'נדלן'
  } else if (key === 'pension') {
    return 'פנסיה'
  } else if (key === 'kupot') {
    return 'קופות'
  } else {
    return 'N/A'
  }
})

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a "For" loop like that :

```
for(let i=0; i < array.length; i++){

  switch (array[i]) {
    case "pension":
      array[i] = 'פנסיה';
      break;

    // Add other cases to the switch with the possible values
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take an object for the replacemenst and map the array and take the key as default value if not in object.

```js
const
    replacements = { balance: 'עוש ומזומן', realestate: 'נדלן', pension: 'פנסיה', kupot: 'קופות' },
    array = ["pension", "realestate", "balance", "kupot", "some value"],
    result = array.map(k => replacements[k] || k);

console.log(result);
```